# GLFW Keyboard events only registering when I've clicked on the screen

Tags: glfw

I have a piece of code that performs some keyboard event functions:

```
void
KeyboardCallback(GLFWwindow */*window*/, int key, int /*scancode*/, int action,
                 int /*mods*/)
{
 
 if (( action == GLFW_PRESS|| action == GLFW_REPEAT ) && key == GLFW_KEY_X) {        
     camera_z = camera_z + (0.1*camera_z);
 }
 if (( action == GLFW_PRESS|| action == GLFW_REPEAT ) &&  key == GLFW_KEY_Z) {
      if (camera_z >= 0.01) {
          camera_z = camera_z - (0.1*camera_z);
      } 
 }
 
}
```

However, the output only appears once I've clicked on the window once. Why is this happening? Is there a way to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your window does not have the input focus. Normally, the window will get the focus when it is shown on screen.

You're able to control this behaviour via window hints (before creation):

- `GLFW_FOCUSED` specifies whether the windowed mode window will be given input focus when created
- `GLFW_FOCUS_ON_SHOW` specifies whether the window will be given input focus when [glfwShowWindow](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga61be47917b72536a148300f46494fc66) is called

To set the input focus at any time, call: [glfwFocusWindow](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga873780357abd3f3a081d71a40aae45a1)